# Login with roles

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to give access to a user according to their role, I have 2 type one Administrator with id 1 and Client with id 2, so far the valid username and password. so the Client can enter the administrative part, and I want him to only have access to the Client's view

This is my function verify of the model:

```
public function Verify($usuario, $contrasena) {

        try {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND contrasena = ?" ;
            $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stm->execute(array($usuario, $contrasena));

            $UsuarioDatos = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            if ($UsuarioDatos == NULL) {

                return FALSE;

            } else {

                return TRUE;

            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            die($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

And this is my login.controller:

```
public function Authenticate() {

        $usuario = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
        $contrasena = ($_REQUEST[('contrasena')]);
        $validar = $this->model->Verify($usuario, $contrasena);

        if ($validar) {
            $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
            $_SESSION['idCategoriaUsu']=$validar['idCategoriaUsu'];

            $_SESSION['Iniciada']='true';


           if($_SESSION['idCategoriaUsu'] == 1){

            header('Location:index.php?c=Home');  
           }
           else {

            header('Location:index.php?c=ClienteNormal');
           }
        } else {

            header('Location: index.php?c=Login&error=true');            
        }

    }
```

Is going directly to this:

```
            else {

            header('Location:index.php?c=ClienteNormal');
           }
```

Comment: Please post your question in English, or post on [es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

your function "Verify" returns a boolean.

Except here:

```
$_SESSION['idCategoriaUsu']=$validar['idCategoriaUsu']
```

you try to access a array.

Comment: How could I do it, I tried but I still can't, i'm starting with this

Answer (score 0):

Quentin Geenens answer is correct,
modify your Verify function:

```
public function Verify($usuario, $contrasena) {
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND contrasena = ?";
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute(array($usuario, $contrasena));
        $UsuarioDatos = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if ($UsuarioDatos == NULL) {
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

to this:

```
public function Verify($usuario, $contrasena) {
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND contrasena = ?";
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute(array($usuario, $contrasena));
        $UsuarioDatos = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if ($UsuarioDatos == NULL) {
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return $UsuarioDatos;
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

if $UsuarioDatos is not NULL it returns the query result.

then modify your Authenticate function:

```
public function Authenticate() {
    $usuario = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
    $contrasena = ($_REQUEST[('contrasena')]);
    $validar = $this->model->Verify($usuario, $contrasena);

    if ($validar) {
        $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
        $_SESSION['idCategoriaUsu']=$validar['idCategoriaUsu'];
        $_SESSION['Iniciada']='true';
        if($_SESSION['idCategoriaUsu'] == 1){
            header('Location:index.php?c=Home');
        }
        else {
            header('Location:index.php?c=ClienteNormal');
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php?c=Login&error=true');            
    }
}
```

to this:

```
public function Authenticate() {
    $usuario = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
    $contrasena = ($_REQUEST[('contrasena')]);
    $validar = $this->model->Verify($usuario, $contrasena);

    if ($validar === FALSE) {
        header('Location: index.php?c=Login&error=true');  
    } else {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION['idCategoriaUsu'] = $validar['idCategoriaUsu'];
        $_SESSION['Iniciada']='true';
        if($_SESSION['idCategoriaUsu'] == 1){
            header('Location:index.php?c=Home');
        }
        else {
            header('Location:index.php?c=ClienteNormal');
        }                  
    }
}
```

I hope this answer helps you